# Ionic2 datetime start from min date

Tags: android, ios, datetime, ionic2, datetimepicker

I have an ion-datetime to display only year:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY" min=2017 max=2050></ion-datetime>
```

But when I open this picker the year start in 2050 and I want to start in 2017.

[image]

There's some way to start from min to max?

Comment: I have the same question.... ☹️

Answer (score 0):

> From Ionic framework docs [DateTime Component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

You have to set date object or simple string value in component file for display selected year.

**E.g if you want to display selected year from current date object then**

> public mTodayDate: any = new Date().toISOString();

**E.g if you want to display selected year '2020' then**

> public mTodayDate: any = "2020";

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY" min="2017" max="2050 [(ngModel)]="mTodayDate"></ion-datetime>
```